# formSubmit hata Null check operator used on a null value with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

```
late String _email;
  late String _password;
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void formSubmit(BuildContext context) async {
    formKey.currentState?.save();
    final _userViewModel = Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context,listen: false);
    try{
      await _userViewModel.signInWithEmailandPassword(_email, _password);
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(userModel: _userViewModel.user!)));
    }catch(e){
      print("formSubmit hata "+e.toString());
    }
  } 
return Scaffold(
      body: Background(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/login.svg",
                  height: size.height * 0.35,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
                RoundedInputField(
                  hintText: "Your Email",
                  onSaved: (String? usedEmail) {
                    _email = usedEmail!;
                  },
                ),
                RoundedPasswordField(
                  onSaved: (String? usedPassword) {
                    _password = usedPassword!;
                  },
                ),
                RoundedButton(
                  text: "GİRİŞ YAP",
                  press: () {
                    formSubmit(context);
                  },
                ),
```

I get an error in formSubmit. It shows the user's id in the terminal, but it doesn't switch to the homepage, it gives the error I wrote. When I remove the null operator, the code is rejected this time, and when I put it, I get this error plss help!!!

Comment: formKey.currentState?.save(); instead of formKey.currentState!.save(); I get the same error when I do

Answer (score 0):

I have written a complete code on how to use `key` to validate `form`. You can run below code in dartpad or here is the [link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1) to dartpad.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Form',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const LoginPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _MyLoginPageState();
}

class _MyLoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  
  late TextEditingController _emailController;
  late TextEditingController _passwordController;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    _emailController = TextEditingController();
    _passwordController = TextEditingController();
    
  }
  
  @override
  dispose(){
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const  Text("Login Screen"),
      ),
      body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
            controller: _emailController,
             decoration: const InputDecoration(
               labelText: "Email",
             ),
              validator: (String? value){
                if(value == null || value.isEmpty){
                  return "Email can not be empty";
                }
                
                // otherwise return null.
                return null;
              } 
              
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
             TextFormField(
            controller: _passwordController,
             decoration: const InputDecoration(
               labelText: "Password",
             ),
               validator: (String? value){
                if(value == null || value.isEmpty){
                  return "password can not be empty";
                }
                
                // otherwise return null.
                return null;
              } 
              
            ),
             const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Login"),
              onPressed: (){
                // validate form
                if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                  _formKey.currentState!.save();
                  // if validation sucess write your logic
                }
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```